# update branch to have history starting at an unrelated branch commit

Tags: git

I'm trying to achieve a specific outcome and have tried a bunch of things, I'm hoping what I want is possible.

Before taking any actions, here's my test setup (illustrated below) I have two unrelated branches (LeftBranch and RightBranch). I want to create a new branch called Main that starts half way up LeftBranch and replays all of the commits from RightBranch on top.

[image: before rebase]

In the end I want the resulting structure to look like:

```
a -> b -> d* -> e* -> f* (RB) (Main)
       \
         -> c (LB)
```

* I understand that `d`, `e` and `f` will have a new git sha. That has no negative impact on my use case.

So far everything I've tried either results in:

```
a -> b -> c (LB)
      \
       -------------------- merge (Main)
                          /
              d -> e -> f (RB)
```

Which is okay but not perfect as the history of d is not actually attached to b like I want.

Or I end up with:

```
a -> b -> c (LB)
d (Main) -> e -> f (RB)
```

When I try to rebase main from b onto d; which is just not at all what I want.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am still not sure of what you want to get in the 2nd part. Is there a question? I mean.... _"moving"_ RB over to where main is in git means just.... moving a pointer, no _big deal_ happens when you move branches around in git. What is the problem with that? Are you _forced_ to keep RB as a branch? What is the problem with that? You want to be able to merge stuff from the original RB into the new main branch?.. IOW, In other words.... I am not sure I understand what the 2nd problem is.

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph. The number of commits is irrelevant when moving a branch (pointer). It's only a label with the hash of its target commit.

Comment: I'll remove the edit - you're both right, there's no problem here. I just need to rebase RightBranch to Main once I've finished. Discarding the original D,E,F commits isn't an actual problem.

Comment: Great! And careful with the wording. You won't _rebase_. You will _move_ the branch (the pointer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible like this:

```
git checkout b
git cherry-pick d # this should not give us any problem if d introduces files that are _not_ the same as the ones in present in revision b
git cherry-pick d..f
```

Now you should have something like what you are asking. You could create a new branch or you might setup rightBtranch and main (as your graph shows as the desired result)

```
git branch -f main
git branch -f rightBranch
```

Comment: Thank you, this will work for me.

A minor improvement would be if there's a way to not strand RightBranch. Do you know if that's possible?

Right now I have a copy of D->E->F from rightbranch

Comment: Not sure I am following. Can you expand in the original question?

Comment: I've updated the main question with an illustration of the result.

Comment: @xoorath based on your edit (and then removal of it), I think maybe you forgot to run the very last command listed in this answer, which is `git branch -f RightBranch`. That would reset `RightBranch` to the same commit as `main` just like in your desired picture.

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout -b Main RightBranch
git rebase --root --onto ab35ed3
```

is the quickest to type, if the rebased history is large and independent you might do better with a graft and filter-branch.

Demo of the above sequence:

```
# replicate your setup:

git init -b LeftBranch rebasedemo; cd $_
seq 3 | tee a b >c; git add .; git commit -m-
git checkout --orphan RightBranch; git commit -m-
for f in *; do sed -i 3s,$,right, $f; git commit -am$f; done
git checkout LeftBranch
for f in *; do sed -i 1s,$,left, $f; git commit -am$f; done

# payload:

git checkout -b Main RightBranch
git rebase --root --onto LeftBranch~
```

Comment: Thank you, this appears to have the same result as the existing answer. Also an acceptable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

### git rebase --onto

I think what you want is a rebase. There are a few different kinds of rebase, and maybe you haven't performed this kind before.

Here's the syntax:

```bash
git rebase --onto NEW_BASE OLD_BASE BRANCH_TO_RELOCATE
```

What this does is pick up your entire branch and move it to a different place.

- Do you wish you had cut your feature branch from a different place? This does that.
- Does your branch need new things that were added to the base branch *after* you cut your branch? This fixes that.

Comment: Given that the OP wants to copy/move _every_ revision of RB, I don't think this will hold water becase... there is no OLD_BASE.... maybe you might pull it off if you use `--root`?

Comment: I think eftshift0 is right, but Tom - if you want to formulate the command clearly in terms of the example, I can let you know what that produces (eftshift0 also has an example setup that is probably correct, although I haven't tried it).

`git rebase --onto <sha_of_d> <sha_of_b> Main` is what I think you're suggesting, but let me know exactly what you mean and are calling NEW_BASE OLD_BASE and BRANCH_TO_RELOCATE and I can confirm the results of what you are suggesting.

Comment: Notice that if the branch to be rebased contains merge commits, the rebase might be a [bit more involved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73340161/23118).