# How to merge branch into main on GIthub with no common history

Tags: git, github

I want to clone one specific branch from a remote repo I do not control on Github. I then want to push that to a repo that I do control on Github.

On the Github UI, I created the new repo I contol under my account. I then cloned the remote repo branch that I do not control onto my local machine and added the new remote repo url to the repo I control. I then pushed that branch locally up to the remote repo I control on Github.

Now on the remote repo I control on Github, I have two branches, `my-new-branch` (which I got from the repo I do not control) and `main` (which is empty). I want to merge `my-new-branch` into `main`. The issue is I can't as there is no shared history. How do I do this? (I realise I probably should have forked the repo I don't control).

Comment: Couldn't you just delete `main` and rename `my-new-branch` as `main`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge branches in 2 different repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468700/how-to-merge-branches-in-2-different-repositories)

Comment: I feel like you're not asking the right question for what you're trying to do. It sounds like you don't care about the existing `main` branch at all so you don't want to "merge". You simply want to replace it with the branch you do care about, and you could just do what @wjandrea suggested, and then force push `main` back out to your repo.

Answer (score 0):

I did just something like that at work this week, although in that case the new repository already had one first commit with a `README.md` file created and I rebased the other repository on top of that (with complete history, including merges).

Now for your case where our `origin`'s `main` branch contains no commits yet, it is really simple and straight forward. As you say `git merge` will complain when attempting to merge from a unrelated repository, however with `main` having no original history to keep you can simply run

```bash
git checkout main
git reset --hard my-new-branch  # I am assuming you have no files added to index/cache/staging, if so those changes will be lost by this command.
```

and now your `main` branch has been set to point to the latest commit from the other repository.

---

Now for the general case where you want to "merge" in parts of an unrelated repository on top of some existing commits, it is a bit more involved.

Assuming the following:

- Two remotes, `origin` and `other_repo`.
- The goal is to merge all of `other_repo/main` on top of `main`.
- The very first commit of `other_repo/main` is tagged `root`.
- No files contain `"` in their file name.

Since rebase's starting reference is *from* but not including, the root commit needs to be cherry-picked first:

```bash
git checkout main
git cherry-pick root  # Might trigger merge conflict. You can use https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3 to ease resolving those.
```

Now the rebase can start:

```bash
git branch rebase_branch other_repo/main
git rebase --rebase-merges --onto main root rebase_branch
```

If you are super lucky, that's it. However you are likely to encounter some of the merges not applying automatically because there were conflicts when the original merge was made and those conflicts were manually resolved then and checked in as part of the merge commit. Git is not able to automatically reproduce that. However we do not need to do any mental work to resolve this again, because for this we only want the merge to be identical to the original so we can just copy content from the corresponding original commit.

First, clone the other repo to a temporary directory:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/your_remote_repo /tmp/other_repo
```

Then for each merge conflict you need to take two manual actions, the rest of the command should be applicable to every conflict:

```bash
# ACTION 1:
# Take note of the commit that git complains "could not merge 123456" or something
# like that. For this example assumed to be 123456.

# ACTION 2:
git status  # Make a list of all the files listed as "Both modified" (or potentially
# added/deleted conflicts) and add them to the files below, one file per line (full,
# relative path, e.g. src/something/README.md).
# Removed files goes in the *.rm file, modified/added in the *.add file.
rm -f   /tmp/other_repo/conflict_files.add /tmp/other_repo/conflict_files.rm
$EDITOR /tmp/other_repo/conflict_files.add /tmp/other_repo/conflict_files.rm

pushd /tmp/other_repo
git checkout 123456
popd

grep -v '^$' /tmp/other_repo/conflict_files.rm  | tr '\015' '\000' | xargs --no-run-if-empty -n1  printf "%s\0" | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty -I@ bash -c 'git rm "@"'
grep -v '^$' /tmp/other_repo/conflict_files.add | tr '\015' '\000' | xargs --no-run-if-empty -n1  printf "%s\0" | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty -I@ bash -c 'cp -v /tmp/other_repo/"@" "@"; git add "@"'

git status # Should now list no files with conflict.
git rebase --continue  # Annoyingly I think there is no way to skip the forced commit
# rewording step. Just close the editor.
```

The long commands above are basically

- grep: ignore blank lines.
- tr: translate newline to ascii null.
- first xargs: annoyingly, [--max-args and --replace are mutually exclusive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538860/4422).
- second xargs: for each file, remove or copy and add.

In a few cases there were conflicts without the clear "could not merge 123456" message, so you have to pick the commit from some of the other lines. Generally it was the last commit listed as far as I remember. You can run `git tag conflict123a 11223344`, `git tag conflict123b 12341234` etc for all the commits mentioned and then press F2 in a `gitk --all` window to locate them. You want the commit that is part of `other_repo/main`.

And then finally

```bash
git checkout main
git merge --ff-only rebase_branch  # --ff-only should not make any difference, just included as a safety precaution.
git branch --delete rebase_branch
rm -rf /tmp/other_repo
# And delete conflict123a, etc tags if created.
```