# Rewording past commits that caused merge conflicts

Tags: git, rebase, git-remote, merge-conflict-resolution

I am practicing how to use git. I made a commit and another contributor made a commit which caused a merge conflict, we then resolved the merge conflict and realized the previous two commits which caused the merge conflict had the same commit message. So we tried to use git rebase -i to go into VIM and reword them using the reword syntax. After saving and exiting the VIM editor, it opened the VIM to change the first commit's commit-message. After changing the text of the file and saving and exiting it gave this prompt.

> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in practice
> error: could not apply ccd42be... updated practice.txt

What is happening and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

By default `git rebase` will not keep merge commits. From the man page:

> By default, a rebase will simply drop merge commits from the todo list, and put the rebased commits into a single, linear branch.

You can change this by giving option `--rebase-merges`:

> With --rebase-merges, the rebase will instead try to preserve the branching structure within the commits that are to be rebased, by recreating the merge commits. Any resolved merge conflicts or manual amendments in these merge commits will have to be resolved/re-applied manually.

So with just `git rebase --interactive` git will drop that commit that had some manual merge conflict resolved in it, and now is complaining "could not apply ..." because it lacks that manual resolvement<sup>1</sup>.

I always run interactive rebase using an alias `ri` set up as `rebase -i --rebase-merges`, however when merge commits contain manual resolvements you still need to resolve them again, [although that is simpler when you just can reuse the original merge commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73340161/23118).

---

Also, you cannot rename files from within the editor, only with `git mv` or `git add` + `git rm`. Strictly speaking git does not track files, but content. So "renames" are done by heuristics.

---

<sup>1</sup> Thus, having merge commits that does not require manual resolvements is much better than having merges that does. There are different opinions about if the best strategy is to merge or rebase feature branches into the main branch. I strongly prefer rebasing, and would like to emphasis that rebasing then creates a "clean" merge commit than then does not need any manual resolvements.